# Angular : After getting response from anchor tag click , that method call again and again on each click of any control on page

Tags: angular, webapi

I am using angular 13. In my application, I have to open a pdf on click on anchor tag so I have done coding.
But Now on click anchor tag i am getting that pdf but after that if I click on any button/control on a page , it will call same page without any proper call. For example , If I click on anchor tag pdf get downloaded and then if I click on Back button that time also pdf get download again.

This generateAppLoad function directly get call again and again.

```
View-apply.component.html
--------------------------


<a (click)="onSendPdf()"> Click on Link</a>

getInformation(){
return combineLatest([
this.Service.EmploymentName,
this.Service.EmploymentCountry,
this.Service.EmploymentEmail,
.....
]);
}

generateAppLoad(EmploymentName,EmploymentCountry,EmploymentEmail,....)
{
const sendAppLoad: SendAppReq = {
application_detail : {
emp_name : EmploymentName.Key,
emp_country:EmploymentCountry.Key
..
},
.
.
application_personal_detail : {
email: EmploymentNameEmail.Key,
phone: EmploymentNamePhone.Key
}

return sendAppLoad;
}


onSendPdf() {
this.getInformation()
.pipe(
map((val1) = this.generateAppLoad(...val1)),
switchMap((param) => this.EmpService.generateForm(param,this.EmpId))
).subscribe({
next:(response) => {
const file - new Blob([response],{type: 'application/pdf'});
const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
window.open(fileURL);


}
error: (error) => {
console.log('error')
}
})
}

onBackClick () {
this.router.navigateByUrl('/Cont-detail')
}
```

map((val1) = this.generateAppLoad(...val1)) this line calling again and again, I am not calling onSendPdf on back button still.

Answer (score 0):

try to change `changeDetectionStrategy` to `onPush`

```js
@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
 changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush // here it is
})
```

Comment: Hi Devendra Kumbhkar, After click anchor it's loading is not stopped , after download the pdf.